# Statistical project directory structure with multiple languages (e.g., R and Splus)?

Tags: r, project-management, splus

Building on the post [How to efficiently manage a statistical analysis project](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2910/how-to-efficiently-manage-a-statistical-analysis-project) and the  [`ProjectTemplate` package](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2010/08/26/projecttemplate/) in R...

Q: How do you build your statistical project directory structure when multiple languages feature heavily (e.g, R AND Splus)?

Most of the discussions on this topic have been limited to projects which primarily use one language. I'm concerned with how to minimize sloppiness, confusion, and breakage, when using multiple languages.

I've included below my current project structure and methods for doing things. An alternative might be to separate code so that I have `./R` and `./Splus` directories---each containing their own `/lib`, `/src`, `/util`, `/tests`, and `/munge` directories.

Q: Which approach would be closest to "best practices" (if any exist)?

- **/data** - data shared across projects
- **/libraries** - scripts shared across projects
- **/projects/myproject** - my working directory. Currently, if I use multiple languages they share this location as their working directory.
- **./data/** - data specific to `/myproject` and symlinks to data in `/data`
- **./cache/** - cached workspaces (e.g., `.RData` files saved using `save.image()` in R or `.sdd` files saved using `data.dump()` in Splus)
- **./lib/** - main project files. Same across all projects. An R project will be run via `source("./lib/main.R")` which in turn runs `load.R`, `clean.R`, `test.R`, `analyze.R`, `.report.R`. Currently, if multiple languages are being used, say, Splus in addition to R, I'll throw `main.ssc`, `clean.ssc`, etc. into this directory as well. Not sure I like this though.
- **./src/** - project-specific functions. Collected one function per file.
- **./util/** - general functions eventually to be packaged. Collected one function per file.
- **./tests/** - files for running test cases. Used by `./lib/test.R`
- **./munge/** - files for cleaning data. Used by `./lib/clean.R`
- **./figures/** - tables and figure output from `./lib/report.R` to be used in the final report
- **./report/** - `.tex` files and symlinks to files in `./figures`
- **./presentation/** - `.tex` files for presentations (usually the `Beamer` class)
- **./temp/** - location for temporary scripts
- **./README**
- **./TODO**
- **./.RData** - for storing R project workspaces
- **./.Data/** - for storing S project workspaces

Comment: this definitely get more answers on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @mpiktas, but this is very important for applied statisticians.

Answer (score 2):

I definitely wouldn't call it "best practices", but my typical project has directories

`R` (which generally contains `prepData.R`, `analysis.R`, `func.R`, and `figs.R`, though could be these could be each split into many files and could use Sweave or [asciidoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/))

`Perl` (mostly for parsing/converting data files)

`RawData` (all original data files)

`Data` (all processed files)

`Notes` (generally notes from the collaborator)

The `R` directory often contains subdirectories `Figs` and `Rcache`.

Particularly important: *version control*!  I like [git](http://git-scm.com/).